# BigNumber math in Postgres to compute Ethereum transactions

Tags: postgresql, ethereum, biginteger, cryptocurrency

Is there any way to handle math over BigNumber in Postgres? I'm especially interested in `uint256` (32 bytes) and having `SUM` over rows.

Right now I'm just storing such numbers as strings then load all rows and manually do `reduce` over them. But I pretty always need to do `SUM` over such data. It might be some extension that can introduce unsigned integer math over `bytea` for example?

Comment: Isn't `numeric` enough?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I did quick math and ~100 decimal digits should be enough for my case. And documentation says it should be ~1000. So I think yes, it will do. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[Thanks to @a_horse_with_no_name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69932061/bignumber-math-in-postgres-to-compute-ethereum-transactions#comment123619740_69932061)

[`numeric` type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-NUMERIC-DECIMAL) can be used to store pretty big numbers. To know what precision should be used this formula can be used:

```
# Example for uint256 in julia lang
max_value = BigInt(1) << (256 + 1) - 1
print( ceil( log10(max_value) ) )
# 78.0
```

So formula says we should use `numeric(78)`.

Comment: Note that you don't really need to constrain the column definition, Postgres will only use as much space as required to store the numbers. Storing `1e78-1` into a `numeric(78)` column takes up as much space as storing it into a `numeric` column.